# find url contaning sub-domains and change to directory in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

php find sub-domains containing ".go.co.in" in loaded html and change to directory

suppose

```
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

find all url contains ".go.co.in" in $html and change as bellow

```
<a href="http://name1.go.co.in to <a href="http://go.co.in/name1
<a href="http://sub.name2.go.co.in to <a href="http://go.co.in/sub.name2
<a href="http://anything.go.co.in to <a href="http://go.co.in/anything
```

i tried many methods but no success please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$repl = preg_replace('~(https?://)(.+?)\.(go\.co\.in)(\S*)~', '$1$3/$2$4' $html);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xB1mO9/1)